# How to set an attribute to FlexSession when user logs in BlazeDS?

Tags: java, tomcat, blazeds

In my application, I want to store some data about the user in his session, when he logs in. It will be retrieved from the database and placed in the FlexSession by calling flexSession.setAttribute('age', n). I am using *Tomcat* with JDBC realm. The question is, how can I place some data in FlexSession, when user authenticates with his login and password?

I know there's a flex.messaging.security.LoginManager.java with

```
 if (username != null && credentials != null)
            {
                Principal authenticated = loginCommand.doAuthentication(username, credentials);

                if (authenticated == null) // Invalid login.
                {
                    SecurityException se = new SecurityException();
                    se.setMessage(INVALID_LOGIN);
                    se.setCode(SecurityException.CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_CODE);
                    throw se;
                }
                setCurrentPrincipal(authenticated);
            }
```

but I'm not sure I can easily override it (the manager is instantiated in the MessageBroker implementation). Therefore I just need to find where the FlexSession is created, with username and password and set some other attribute.

Or I can use FlexSessionListener, by adding

```
FlexSession.addSessionCreatedListener(new CustomFlexSessionListener());
```

but to where?

Looking forward to  your ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I think I found it: http://oncer-l.iteye.com/blog/1897972, use bootstrap service

Answer (score 0):

The solution here: http://oncer-l.iteye.com/blog/1897972.
A new Bootstrap Service needs to be created and specified in the services-config file:

```
<service id="listener" class="test.ListenersBootstrapService" />
```

It will be executed on the servlet startup, so in it we add:

```
@Override
public void initialize(String arg0, ConfigMap arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("hello from init bootstrap listener!");

    MyFlexSessionListener sessionListener = new MyFlexSessionListener(); 
    FlexSession.addSessionCreatedListener(sessionListener); 

}
```

where

```
class MyFlexSessionListener implements FlexSessionListener { 

    public void sessionCreated(FlexSession session) 
    { 
        System.out.println("FlexSession created: " + session.getId()); 
        session.setAttribute("gender", "male");     
    } 
}
```

Many thanks to the author of the article.

The problem is, however, that FlexContext.getUserPrincipal() or session.getUserPrincipal() return null, possibly because the session is created first, and then authenticated. Need to find the way to listen for property change event on userPrincipal.